# EF Core migration errors with the located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to generate a database from the terminal of VS code using SQL Operations Studio, whenever I try to generate a migration this error occurs.

```
dotnet ef migrations add init
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.401/DotnetTools/dotnet-ef/2.1.2/tools/netcoreapp2.1/any/tools/netcoreapp2.0/any/ef.dll'. The located assembly's manifestdefinition does not match the assembly  reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This is how my `.csproj` looks like now

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: do you have .core 2.1.2 framework?

Comment: @viveknuna yes I have.

Comment: I think you can raise bug in EF Core

Comment: I resolve the problem adding `<RuntimeIdentifier>osx.10.12-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

inside the `<PropertyGroup>` tag

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` package added to the wrong project.

I added the package to `project A (netcore)`. Later I decided to make project A to target `netstandard`. I then created `Project B (netcore)` which reference `project A (now netstandard)`.

When I try to create migration in project B the build succeeds but migration would fail because `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` was referenced in A instead of B. Moving the nuget reference to B fixes the problem.